# HTTPCookieProcessor not serving cookies

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I am trying to access a website that requires cookies. Using urllib2 and cookielib I am able to get a response from the site. The HTML printout informs me that I am not getting access with the line:

```
<h2>Cookies Disabled</h2>
<p> class="share-prompt"><strong>Cookies must be enabled.</strong></p>
```

I cannot understand where I am going wrong. Code below:

```
import urllib2, cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http':"http://216.208.156.69:3128"}),urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))
request = urllib2.Request("[website]")
response = opener.open(request)

print response.read()
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks good. For example the output from this

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))
params = urllib.urlencode({'cookie_name': 'cookie_value'})
request = urllib2.Request('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set?' + params)
opener.open(request)
request = urllib2.Request('http://httpbin.org/cookies')
response = opener.open(request)
print response.read()
```

is

```
{
  "cookies": {
    "cookie_name": "cookie_value"
  }
}
```

Without showing us the url you use not much can be done.

Comment: What I cant understand is why in your line 4 I would need to define the cookies - is this not something that the site should be passing to me?

Comment: I looked further into this - nothing is storing from the site into the cookieJar. By comparison I ran it pointed at google.com and received 4 cookies. hummm....

Comment: @tgunn *(...)is this not something that the site should be passing to me?* Yes, normally server sends cookies and browser sends them back. Here, I'm using very nice httpbin.org service which can be instructed to send cookies to me. This way I can simulate behavior of *normal* web server. In your real code you don't need to set cookies yourself like this. *By comparison I ran it pointed at google.com and received 4 cookies.* Sometimes web servers act differently based on User-Agent http header you send them. Try changing this header to match what your browser sends.